# Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE (Or) ERROR: Build step failed with exception org.codehaus.cargo.c

Tags: jenkins, tomcat

I was trying to solve this myself, but I haven't been able to solve this issue for three days. I have added user in tomcat-user.xml and tomcat port number is everything looks good, even my tomcat running is fine. But since when I was trying to deploy in tomcat server I am getting this error:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Hi, can you post the error as actual text instead of images? [Posting code or errors as images is not preferred for different reasons.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this problem for some hours and I'm a completely noob in this area. I tried to do it with the "Deploy to container" plugin but for some reason my tomcat server was not picking up.

I tried to change the port number from **8080** to **8084** but still failed.

and that's when I decided to write a script instead of using the plugin. I created a new job with freestyle and under build steps: chose Execute shell.

this is my original code: cp /root/.jenkins/workspace/maven\ package/target/cloudbots_webapp.war /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.62/webapps

you need to find where the .war file is getting created when you run the package job. view the console and you'll see something called : "Attempting to" above that you'll see that they are trying to copy one file to a different folder.

ex: /file1/ to /file2/

using cp command I entered the directory of both of them and saved it. you also need to change the trigger to run the build after maven package.

Cheers!